# Error while executing command: Open Android SDK Manager

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

[image: Scree shot or error with detail:]

Error while executing command: Open Android SDK Manager...

Comment: Any news on this? I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Support repiled me:

1. JDK 1.7: http://download.xamarin.com/Installer/MonoForAndroid/jdk-7u71-windows-i586.exe
2. Android SDK: http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r23.0.2-windows.exe​
3. GTK#: http://download.xamarin.com/GTKforWindows/Windows/gtk-sharp-2.12.26.msi
4. Xamarin Studio: http://download.xamarin.com/studio/Windows/XamarinStudio-5.5.4.15-0.msi
5. Xamarin for Windows: http://download.xamarin.com/XamarinforVisualStudio/Windows/Xamarin.VisualStudio_Setup-3.8.150.msi

Comment: If it also not works, dont waist your time to solve it, just format your system and re-install all.